# Making a smooth, dynamic website

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

I am seeking to create a website with a very smooth layout, like it is all dynamic and not just BLAM, heres a website.

Let me elaborate:
I got this setup for now, just so you can figure what I am trying to get working.
[image]

What I mean by dynamic is, that I want when the page have been loaded I would the image to come sliding in (maybe the banner too, haven't decided all design yet, just throwing suggestions.). When image have slided in I would like it to be expanding and despanding slowly, like it's always in movement. When hovered over it should expand slightly more and stop it's movements while it is hovered.

This are the main needs I am searching for, and I am a little clueless on how it is done.
I was thinking javascript was obvious, but I've failed any guides I've found and therefore belive I need some direct help.

Highly appreciated, thanks!

I've tried making the image fade in and out with jquery, but doesn't seem to work, heres my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <style>
        body {
            background: url("images/BG.png") repeat;
        }
        .logo {
            width: 640px;
            height: 360px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 40%;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .middlebanner {
            width: 100%;
            height: 60%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        </style>

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s) in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <title>Electronic Future Copenhagen - Choose your game</title>
        <img src="images/middlebanner.png" class="middlebanner" />
        <img src="images/logo5.png" class="logo" />

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <a href="http://jquery.com">jQuery</a>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>"

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("#logo").animate({
            left: "300"
        }, {
            duration: 2000
        });

        $( "#logo" ).hover(function() {
            $( this ).fadeOut( 100 );
            $( this ).fadeIn( 500 );
        });


        });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need a graphic designer first, not a programmer.

Comment: Javascript based animations (essentially changing height, width and position of elements) or CSS based animations. jQuery and other libraries come with a bunch of existing animation code. Start there.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I am creating my images myself at the moment. Afterall most of it is just being used for learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jpj7S/14/) to get you on your way...

Just animate divs and images etc to get the desired effect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#efclogo").animate({
        left: "300"
    }, {
        duration: 2000
    });
});
```

Added a hover over function so you can see how that works too.

```
$( "#efclogo" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).fadeOut( 100 );
  $( this ).fadeIn( 500 );

});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jpj7S/16/)

Comment: @KrownScripter - I suggest you read this quick article before you start then: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: No probs! Good luck bro.

Comment: Tried doing this with you code, but seems like I messed a little up. Posted an edit of the code, if you could check it and see what is wrong :)

Comment: opened the fiddle didn't realize it was a link (woopzie, checking it out :P

Comment: @KrownScripter - Not sure if you downloaded the Jquery files, but I let Google just host them... So looking at your code, your Link to Jquery library needs to look like this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` you were missing the `http:` also, there seems to be a lot of other script tags that you dont need ;) What I usually do to make sure my jquery is loading is add an `alert('Jquery is working');` in that `document.ready` function. ;) Keep me posted with your attempts.

Comment: I made it work :D I already downloaded the jquery and my mistake was in the CSS and HTML :) Now it's working and I am gratefull for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a part of code that might help you:

```
//Above is pure JS(no jQuery) which does the loading part, aka pre-loader
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Here is when loading is 100% completed, will trigger the function
    $(window).load(function() {
         loadComplete();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you should get started when you decide to use jQuery library.

**Slide down**
https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

**Animate**
https://api.jquery.com/animate/

**Hover**
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

Your idea might be a little confusing to site visitors. Think about a page you are looking at where everything is flowing around so you cant find anything.

The key is to have a "normal" page and let **some** eyecatching elements fly around.

The technical aspect depends on what you want to archieve. First you need to think about the browser performance (on mobile especially).

One way to archieve this would be jQuery animate, anotherone would be css3 animate/transition. The easiest example of jQuery animate is in the api: https://api.jquery.com/animate/. Apparently I dont have a css tutorial in mind.

Comment: Appreciate your answer :) I am not seeking to make confusion, but I would like clickable items to be just slightly dynamic and moving, not jumping around of course. For the matter of the banner it is mainly just for an "intro" to the website :) EDIT: What I am creating here is an introduction to the main site, this will only contain few clickable pictures redirecting you to different main sites